# Regex Replace between groups

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

So I have the following regex.replace in C#:

```
Regex.Replace(inputString, @"^([^,]*,){5}(.*)", @"$1somestring,$2");
```

where `5` is a variable number in code, but that's not really relevant since at the time of execution it will always have a set value (like `5`, for example). Same with `somestring,`.

Essentially I want to input `somestring,` between the two groups. The output works for `somestring,$2`, but `$1` is just printed as `$1`. So say whatever `(.*)` grabs `= "2, a, f2"` the resulting string I'd get out is `$1somestring,2,a,f2` no matter what `$1` is. Is this because of the repeating group feature `{5}`? If so, how do I grab the collection of repeats and put it in place of where I have `$1` right now?

Edit: I know the first group captures correctly, as well. I grab the content of `somestring,` using this regex:

```
Regex.Match(line, @"^([^,]*,){5}([0-9]+\.[0-9]+),.*");
```

The first part is identical the the first group in the replacement regex, and it works fine, so there shouldn't be an issue (and they're both used on the same string).

Edit2:

Ok I'll try to explain more of the process since someone said it was hard to understand. I have three variables, `line` a string I work with, and `latIndex` and `lonIndex` which are just ints (tells me between what ,'s two doubles I look for are located). I have the two following matches:

```
var latitudeMatch = Regex.Match(line, @"^([^,]*,){" + latIndex + @"}([0-9]+\.[0-9]+),.*");
var longitudeMatch = Regex.Match(line, @"^([^,]*,){" + lonIndex + @"}([0-9]+\.[0-9]+),.*");
```

I then grab the doubles:

```
var latitude = latitudeMatch.Groups[2].Value;
var longitude = longitudeMatch.Groups[2].Value;
```

I use these doubles to get a string from a web API, which i store in a variable called `veiRef`. Then I want to insert these after the doubles, using the following code (insert after lat or lon, depending on which one appears last):

```
if (latIndex > lonIndex)
{
    line = Regex.Replace(line, @"^([^,]*,){" + (latIndex+1) + @"}(.*)",$@"$1{veiRef},$2");
}
else
{
    line = Regex.Replace(line, @"^([^,]*,){" + (lonIndex + 1) + @"}(.*)", $@"$1{veiRef},$2");
}
```

However, this results in a string `line` which doesn't have the content of $1 inserted before it ($2 works fine).

Comment: Just a habit / code standard. I basically use it unless I *want* to use special string characters. It's a C# escape character (signifies verbatim string).

Comment: Just for clarification someone asked why I used @ in the replacement string. Just putting it here in case someone gets confused why I wrote that comment.

Comment: I have a string like this: `a, s, f, double, double, 12, sd, 1`. The place where the doubles appear is dynamic, and I want to insert something after the doubles (hence `5` being a variable). So using this example, I want to turn the string into: `a, s, f, double, double, somestring, 12, sd, 1`.

Comment: So in actuality my regexes look something like this: `var latitudeMatch = Regex.Match(line, @"^([^,]*,){" + latIndex + @"}([0-9]+\.[0-9]+),.*");` and                                `line = Regex.Replace(line, @"^([^,]*,){" + (latIndex+1) + @"}(.*)",$@"$1{veiRef}$2");`

Comment: ..why do people keep removing their comments after I answer them

Comment: Give some proper format input and expected output, it seems hard to understand

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman
i expanded the question. I was thinking this information was kind of superfluous for my question, but there you go.

Comment: @user1339253 [Look here](http://ideone.com/SFa5nX), it works. What is your `veiRef`? It is also better to use `$"${{1}}{veiRef.Replace("$","$$")}$2"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
Doesn't look like it works to me. It's not printing the beginning of the string `a, s, f, double, double,`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
Veiref is just a string that's downloaded from an API.

Comment: @user1339253: I have updated the demo, http://ideone.com/SFa5nX. I did not know you need to access the whole initial part of the match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a repeated capturing group at the start of the pattern that you need to turn into a non-capturing one and wrap with a capturing group. Then, you may access the whole part of the match with the `$1`  backreference.

```
var line = "a, s, f, double, double, 12, sd, 1";
var latIndex = 5;
var pat = $@"^((?:[^,]*,){{{latIndex+1}}})(.*)";
// Console.WriteLine(pat); // => ^((?:[^,]*,){6})(.*)
var veiRef = "str";
line = Regex.Replace(line, pat, $"${{1}}{veiRef.Replace("$","$$")}$2");
Console.WriteLine(line); // => a, s, f, double, double, 12,str sd, 1
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/SFa5nX)

The pattern - `^((?:[^,]*,){6})(.*)` - now contains `((?:[^,]*,){6})` after `^`, and this is now what `$1` holds after a match is found.

Since your replacement string is dynamic, you need to make sure any `$` inside gets doubled (hence, `.Replace("$","$$")`) and that the first backreference is unambiguous, thus it should look like `${1}` (it will work regardless whether the `veiRef` starts with a digit or not).

Replacement string in details:

- It is an interpolated string literal...
- `$"` - declaration of the interpolated string literal (start)
- `${{1}}` - a literal `${1}` string (the `{` and `}` must be doubled to denote literal symbols)
- `{veiRef.Replace("$","$$")}` - a piece of C# code inside the interpolated string literal (we delimit this part where code is permitted with single `{...}`)
- `$2` - a literal `$2` string
- `"` - end of the interpolated string literal.

Comment: Using this: `line = Regex.Replace(line, pat, $"${{1}}{veiRef.Replace("$", "$$")}$2");` seems to work. I've not seen this syntax before. Could you explain it?

Comment: Thank you. I still don't quite get it (the stuff about doubling some symbols, and why it's not necessary for $2 but it is for the rest), but I guess I'll try to review it again later.

Comment: If you replace with `$1$5$2` and expect a literal `$5` (your `veiRef` contents) to appear in the result, you need to double `$` symbols in the replacement string. If your `veiRef` starts with a digit, you must use an unambiguous backreference syntax, `${1}`. E.g. if your `veiRef` starts with `3`, your replacement will look like `$13` and the regex engine would be looking for the 13th capturing group in your pattern, and would not find it, right? `${1}3` will replace with the first capturing group and then `3`.

Comment: Both the `veiRef` string and $1 does indeed start with a digit. So ${1} = $1 just that it works with strings that starts with digits? Or ${1} = verbatim $1?  If so then I understand this part now. Why replace every $ in veiRef with $$, though?

Comment: It is not important what `$1` holds. `$1` and `$15` will work differently, you may do some tests with `veiRef` like `5stars`. "Verbatim" is not the term you may use here. Unambiguous. As for replacing dollars in the replacement string, just know that to replace  with a dollar, it should be doubled.  As a test just replace without the extra Replace and veiRef set to `price: $1`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an extra group around the repeating capturing group seems to provide the desired output for the example you gave.

```
Regex.Replace("a, s, f, double, double, 12, sd, 1", @"^(([^,]*,){5})(.*)", @"$1somestring,$3");
```

I'm not an expert on RegEx and someone can probably explain it better than I, but:-

Group 1 is the set of 5 repeating capture groups
Group 2 is the last of the repeating capture groups
Group 3 is the text after the 5 repeating capture groups.

Comment: Hmm doesn't seem to work for me. I edited my regex to                                  `line = Regex.Replace(line, @"^(([^,]*,){" + (latIndex+1) + @"})(.*)",$@"$1{veiRef}$2");`

Comment: For clarity, the pattern in that regex becomes `"^(([^,]*,){6})(.*)"` after compiling with the testing input I'm using. It still turns the result into `$1somestring,[value of (.*)]`

Comment: Edit: Just missed that $3... sorry. But the behavior is still the same using $3 in the regex. $1 is still printed as $1, and not the actual value.

Comment: Strange, you're regex works for me!!. Another option, have you tried named groups?? `Regex.Replace("a, s, f, double, double, 12, sd, 1", @"^(?<begining>([^,]*,){5})(?<end>.*)", @"${begining}somestring,${end}");`

Comment: If you look at the other answer my problem seemed to be that my insertion-string (as well as the first group) both started with a number in my case, which caused regex to flip out. I didn't know $groups weren't verbatim.